How to prevent text selection from showing up when it's scrolled out of view?
On IOS, I noticed that the selection box shows up when text is selected, even when the selection is scrolled out of view. Is there a way to prevent that?

This screenshot was achieved with a setup like this:


#scrollable {
  background: #EEE;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
<div id="scrollable">
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
  abcdefb<br />
</div>



I've tried adding something like

#scrollable::selection {
  z-index: 0;
}

but that doesn't work

which select box?

By selection box, I mean the blue area you see below the grey box. It was achieved by scrolling down in the box, selecting some text, and then scrolling up again. I'd like that blue area to scroll out of view along with the text.

It's a buggy feature that happens on iOS. Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, ... in OS

all browsers on IOS use Safari's rendering engine, so it makes sense that all of them have this issue

Someone said it only happens on safari, but the comments are gone.

Apparently ::selection doesn't work on IOS (https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Aselection) so even workarounds sensing scroll with JS and altering colors is not going to work.
